# How to convert string with fraction to float in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, floating-point, fractions

I'm prepping some data to insert into MySQL. Unfortunately some of the data is in the form `100½`. I need to convert this to a float, but obviously `float(100½)` fails.

Is there a method in Python that can handle this conversion? I'm not opposed to hard coding something, but I may encounter `⅝` or other fractions in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> float(sum(fractions.Fraction(x) for x in unidecode.unidecode('100½').split()))
100.5
```

[`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html)

[`unidecode`](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, do you know if there is a unidecode equivalent in stdlib?

Answer (score 1):

```
from unidecode import unidecode
from fractions import Fraction
a = unidecode('100½').split()
print(float(int(a[0])+Fraction(a[1])))
```